# Бэкап Elasticsearch

Tags: windows, elasticsearch

При попытке добавить репозиторий для бэкапа на windows, я получаю следующую ошибку:
PUT http://localhost:9200/_snapshot/my_backup

```
{
    "error": {
        "root_cause": [
            {
                "type": "repository_exception",
                "reason": "[my_backup] location [c:\\es-backup\\] doesn't match any of the locations specified by path.repo because this setting is empty"
            }
        ],
        "type": "repository_exception",
        "reason": "[my_backup] failed to create repository",
        "caused_by": {
            "type": "repository_exception",
            "reason": "[my_backup] location [c:\\es-backup\\] doesn't match any of the locations specified by path.repo because this setting is empty"
        }
    },
    "status": 500
}
```

В конфиге добавил:

```
path.data: [ "c:\\es-backup\\" ]
```

Решилось добавлением path.repo
Другая ошибка:

```
Illegal char <:> at index 1: с:\\es-backup.
```

Решено: буква диска должна быть большой.
Спасибо)

Comment: ну а жалуется-то он на path.repo

Comment: @etki мда)0. Спасибо, та ошибка исчезла. Появилась новая: Illegal char <:> at index 1: с:\\es-backup. Буква диска должна быть большой, спасибо, все починилось.

Comment: Приведите, пожалуйста, текущие настройки. Это может быть вызвано, например, отсутствием кавычек в yml, но гадать - дело не очень хорошее